# Calculate average words in sentence

Tags: php

In my PHP project I am trying to calculate average words count per sentence.

When I input few sentences everything works as it should.

Sentence:

```
"content": "Cassieres Werk zur der verbindet die des mit an."
```

Result:

```
"wordsPerSentences": "9.0"
```

**BUT**, when I input just one sentence and without full stop the average value is "0".

Content:

```
"content": "Cassieres Werk zur der verbindet die des mit an"
```

Result:

```
"wordsPerSentences": "0.0"
```

**Also**, problem is that when I input *'full stop'* and *space* it adds to the score or *comma* and *space* after the word?

Content:

```
"content": "Cassieres Werk zur der, verbindet die des mit an. "
```

Result:

```
"wordsPerSentences": "10.0"
```

How can I cover that condition among others?

***EDIT*: This conditions are solved except the one where there is "comma" between just two words in a sentence, it returns "1", and should "2".**

My code:

```
$tokens    = ',.;';


$sentences = [];
  $chunk     = strtok(trim($text), $tokens);

  // Handle empty $text
  if (!is_string($chunk)) {
    return 0;
  }

  do {
    $sentences[] = $chunk;
  } while ($chunk = strtok($tokens));

  $countWords = function (int $carry, string $item) {
    return $carry + count(array_filter(explode(' ', $item)));
  };

  $totalWords = array_reduce($sentences, $countWords, 0);

  return $totalWords / count($sentences);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [str_word_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php):

```
echo str_word_count('Cassieres Werk zur der verbindet die des mit an.'); //9
echo str_word_count('Cassieres Werk zur der verbindet die des mit an.   '); //9
echo str_word_count('    Cassieres Werk zur der verbindet die des mit an.   '); //9
echo str_word_count('    Cassieres Werk zur der verbindet     
die    des    mit an.   '); //9
echo str_word_count('  Cassieres Werk zur der verbindet die des mit an   ');
```

It'll count all words, and ignore break/line spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_word_count.

```
echo str_word_count('Cassieres Werk zur der verbindet die des mit an.');
```

Answer (score 0):

the following function will return the average number of words per sentence. I hope this will solve your problem.

```
<?php

/**
 * Average words per sentence
 *
 * Assumptions:
 * - Only space character is used to separate words.
 * - Only '?' and '.' are used to separate sentences.
 * - Special characters ',', ';', '-' are removed from text.
 *
 * @author  Jawira Portugal
 * @license do whatever you want
 */
function str_average(string $text)
{
  // Removing "not word" characters in $text
  $special = [',', ';', '-'];
  $text    = str_replace($special, ' ', $text);

  $tokens = '.?';
  $chunk  = strtok(trim($text), $tokens);

  // Handle empty $text
  if (!is_string($chunk)) {
    return 0;
  }

  $sentences = [];
  do {
    $sentences[] = $chunk;
  } while ($chunk = strtok($tokens));

  $countWords = function (int $carry, string $item) {
    return $carry + count(array_filter(explode(' ', $item)));
  };

  $totalWords = array_reduce($sentences, $countWords, 0);

  return $totalWords / count($sentences);
}

echo str_average(''), PHP_EOL; // 0
echo str_average('  ,   '), PHP_EOL; // 0
echo str_average("Hello world, this is a test..."), PHP_EOL; // 6
echo str_average("Hello world? this is a test..."), PHP_EOL; // 3
echo str_average("Cassieres Werk zur der verbindet die des mit an."), PHP_EOL; // 9
echo str_average("Cassieres Werk zur der verbindet die des mit an"), PHP_EOL; // 9
echo str_average("Cassieres Werk zur der, verbindet die des mit an. "), PHP_EOL; // 9
echo str_average("...Hello world. foo bar baz? One two three four. "), PHP_EOL; // 3
```

**EDIT** I rewrote the function to split sentences with "." and "?".

Comment: Sorry, actually, two words in a sentence with comma are returning "1". It should be "2", right? @jawira

Comment: A added ? in the middle of two words it's "2" and it should be "1" right? @jawira

Comment: @pohofo well, this function gives the **average** of words in each sentence. Because ',' is inside $tokens variable it is used to split a string in two sentences. For example "hello,world" is considered to be two sentences, so "2 words/2 sentences=1"

Comment: @pohofo If you want to split sentences only using period (**.**) then change `$tokens    = '.';`, the $tokens variables is used to split sentences.

Comment: @pohofo well, finally I modified the solution. I hope is what you need.